# What is the difference between like and like line of in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I have one doubt. May I know what the difference between `LIKE` and `LIKE LINE OF` in ABAP is? I have seen somewhere that while declaring the work area they are declaring.

```
wa LIKE it_one
wa LIKE LINE OF it_one
```

Comment: I wonder if you have taken a look at the online documentation at http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/9b/239fa610de11d295390000e8353423/content.htm

Answer (score 6):

`LIKE LINE OF` means that the variable will be of the table line type.

`LIKE` means that the variable will be exactly of the same type as the one sitting after this key word.

Example

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_my_example_structure,
    my_example_field1 TYPE i,
    my_example_field2 TYPE n,
  END OF t_my_example_structure.

TYPES tt_my_example_structure TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t_my_example_structure.

DATA: l_tab_my_example TYPE tt_my_example_structure.

* has structure of row of l_tab_my_example so in this case t_my_example_structure.
DATA: l_str_my_example LIKE LINE OF l_tab_my_example.

* is exactly the same table type as l_tab_my_example so in this case tt_my_example_structure.
DATA: l_tab_like_my_example LIKE l_tab_my_example.

* I use it often for LOOP AT <tab> ASSIGNING <fs>.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_str_my_example> LIKE LINE OF l_tab_my_example.
```

Comment: Just to refine this - `table_line` is technically not a data type. What you most probably mean is an unstructured internal table. In any case - not just for structured tables! - `LIKE LINE OF` refers to the line type (call it record type if you like) of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will rephrase the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the difference is when you pass table into subroutine with USING or TABLES.

In 1st case you will get a table **without** headerline, thus `WA_LIKE` will be a table too.

In 2nd case `IT_DATA` will be a table **with** headerline: this causes `IT_DATA` actually means `IT_DATA` as structure or `IT_DATA[]` as table, depending on context. Particulary, `DATA ... LIKE IT_DATA` will refer to headerline, and not entire internal table.

You may check this using a debugger:

```
DATA T_DATA TYPE STRING_TABLE.

PERFORM TEST_01 USING  T_DATA.
PERFORM TEST_02 TABLES T_DATA.

FORM TEST_01 USING IT_DATA TYPE STRING_TABLE.
  DATA : WA_LIKE LIKE         IT_DATA  "This is a Table
       , WA_LINE LIKE LINE OF IT_DATA.
  BREAK-POINT.
ENDFORM.

FORM TEST_02 TABLES IT_DATA TYPE STRING_TABLE.
  DATA : WA_LIKE LIKE         IT_DATA  "This is a String
       , WA_LINE LIKE LINE OF IT_DATA.
  BREAK-POINT.
ENDFORM.
```